# Horizontal Background Scrolling Images

Tags: css, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to find a way to get my backgrounds to scroll horizontally similar to this website (scroll down on the homepage to "our services"):

https://www.lasmarthome.com/

I'm using Oxygen builder on Wordpress.

Here's what I have so far.

```
<div id="div_block-89-2" class="ct-div-block "><h1 id="headline-90-2" class="ct-headline">Fire Sprinkler Installation</h1></div>
```

```
body
{
    background: #eee; /* For visibility of elements. */
}

div#div_block-89-2.ct-div-block { 
    align-items: flex-start;
    background-image: url("https://fireguardians.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/xUntitled-design-82.png.pagespeed.ic.Mko3_9o9wR.webp");
    background-size: cover;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    color: #404040;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    font-family: "Roboto Slab";
    height: 330px;
    justify-content: center;
    line-height: 25.6px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

h1#headline-90-2.ct-headline { 
    box-sizing: inherit;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Roboto Slab";
    font-size: 55px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

@media not all, not all { 
    div#div_block-89-2.ct-div-block { 
        max-width: 100%;
        min-height: 1px;
    }

    h1#headline-90-2.ct-headline { 
        max-width: 100%;
        min-height: 1px;
    }

}
```

https://codepen.io/purethor/pen/ZEJQmje

Thank you!